# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace' during change array

Tags: python, arrays, replace, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I'm don't have much experience with Python and I'm having a problem with making a web crawler. I'm trying to change a item in an array it gives this error

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

```
import urllib
import mechanize
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getGoogle(link):
        br = mechanize.Browser()
        br.set_handle_robots(False)
        br.addheaders=[('User-agent','chrome')]

        term = link.replace(" ", "+")
        query = "http://www.google.com/search?q="+term
        htmltext = br.open(query).read()
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(htmltext, "html.parser")
        search = soup2.findAll('div', attrs={'id':'search'})
        searchtext = str(search[:])
        soup3 = BeautifulSoup(searchtext, "html.parser")
        list_items = soup3.findAll('li', attrs={'class', 'g'})
        for li in list_items:
                for h3 in li.findAll('h3'):
                        for a in h3.findAll('a'):
                                regex = "q(?!.*q).*?amp"
                                pattern = re.compile(regex)
                                source_url = re.findall(pattern, str(a))
                                results_array = [source_url]

                                for result in results_array:
                                        result.append(str(source_url[:].replace("q=","").replace("&amp", "")))

                                        for url in results_array:
                                                r = requests.get(url)

                                                soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

                                                g_data = soup.find_all(attrs={"name":"viewport"})

                                                for item in g_data:
                                                        return r.url, 'bevat een viewport'
                                                        break
                                                else:
                                                        return r.url, 'bevat GEEN viewport'
```

Comment: You missed a paren: `result.append(str(source_url).replace("q=","").replace("&amp", ""))` - ForceBru's answer does what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
result.append(''.join(source_url).replace("q=","").replace("&amp", ""))
```

Comment: When I put this in, I receive another error, maybe you could help me with this as well. **MissingSchema: Invalid URL '': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://?**

I printed out **url** 
`q=http://www.essenburgh.nl/&amp

qLd33dBg">tpevk.nl | Tandartsenpraktijk <b>Essenburg</b> &amp
q=https://www.essenburgmultimedia.nl/&amp
q=https://www.essenburgmultimedia.nl/vacatures/&amp
q=https://nl.linkedin.com/in/thomasvandenessenburg&amp

q=http://www.funda.nl/koop/dordrecht/appartement-48399335-essenburg-78/&amp
q=http://www.funda.nl/koop/dordrecht/huis-48248580-essenburg-13/&amp`

Comment: @Web4life, it's difficult to judge without knowing how `source_url` looks like.

Comment: I've printed `source_url` for you.

`[]
['q=http://www.essenburgh.nl/&amp']
[]
['qLd33dBg">tpevk.nl | Tandartsenpraktijk <b>Essenburg</b> &amp']
['q=https://www.essenburgmultimedia.nl/&amp']
['q=https://www.essenburgmultimedia.nl/vacatures/&amp']
['q=https://nl.linkedin.com/in/thomasvandenessenburg&amp']
[]
['q=http://www.funda.nl/koop/dordrecht/appartement-48399335-essenburg-78/&amp']
['q=http://www.funda.nl/koop/dordrecht/huis-48248580-essenburg-13/&amp']`

Comment: @Web4life, then you should do this for each element of this list.